# New Set Array returing Wrong data

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to get distinct coaGrpId from ldgrwisesum useState but getting null values in array object and length as 310 which is my requires array object.

below is the ldgrwisesum  useState from where i stored the data

```
[
    {
        "siteCode": "ANKL",
        "ldgrGrp": "L",
        "coaGrpNm": "Security Deposit - Others",
        "coaGrpCode": "CASDR0500044",
        "coaGrpId": 310,
        "opening": 10000,
        "prdDr": 0,
        "prdCr": 0,
        "closing": 10000
    },
    {
        "siteCode": "AYDH",
        "ldgrGrp": "L",
        "coaGrpNm": "Security Deposit - Others",
        "coaGrpCode": "CASDR0500003",
        "coaGrpId": 310,
        "opening": 5000,
        "prdDr": 0,
        "prdCr": 0,
        "closing": 5000
    },
    {
        "siteCode": "BIAL",
        "ldgrGrp": "L",
        "coaGrpNm": "Security Deposit - Others",
        "coaGrpCode": "CASDR0500010",
        "coaGrpId": 310,
        "opening": 41400,
        "prdDr": 0,
        "prdCr": 0,
        "closing": 41400
    },
    {
        "siteCode": "BLSH",
        "ldgrGrp": "L",
        "coaGrpNm": "Security Deposit - Others",
        "coaGrpCode": "CASDR0500013",
        "coaGrpId": 310,
        "opening": 5000,
        "prdDr": 0,
        "prdCr": 0,
        "closing": 5000
    },
    {
        "siteCode": "BLSH",
        "ldgrGrp": "L",
        "coaGrpNm": "Security Deposit - Others",
        "coaGrpCode": "CASDR0500016",
        "coaGrpId": 310,
        "opening": 1178176,
        "prdDr": 0,
        "prdCr": 0,
        "closing": 1178176
    },
    {
        "siteCode": "BLSH",
        "ldgrGrp": "L",
        "coaGrpNm": "Security Deposit - Others",
        "coaGrpCode": "CASDR0500028",
        "coaGrpId": 310,
        "opening": -294710,
        "prdDr": 0,
        "prdCr": 0,
        "closing": -294710
    },
    {
        "siteCode": "CKBL",
        "ldgrGrp": "L",
        "coaGrpNm": "Security Deposit - Others",
        "coaGrpCode": "CASDR0500026",
        "coaGrpId": 310,
        "opening": 3890,
        "prdDr": 0,
        "prdCr": 0,
        "closing": 3890
    },
    {
        "siteCode": "CPLN",
        "ldgrGrp": "L",
        "coaGrpNm": "Security Deposit - Others",
        "coaGrpCode": "CASDR0500027",
        "coaGrpId": 310,
        "opening": 139371,
        "prdDr": 0,
        "prdCr": 0,
        "closing": 139371
    },
    {
        "siteCode": "DMR5",
        "ldgrGrp": "L",
        "coaGrpNm": "Security Deposit - Others",
        "coaGrpCode": "CASDR0500018",
        "coaGrpId": 310,
        "opening": 37200,
        "prdDr": 0,
        "prdCr": 0,
        "closing": 37200
    },
    {
        "siteCode": "DMR7",
        "ldgrGrp": "L",
        "coaGrpNm": "Security Deposit - Others",
        "coaGrpCode": "CASDR0500039",
        "coaGrpId": 310,
        "opening": 57000,
        "prdDr": 0,
        "prdCr": 0,
        "closing": 57000
    },
    {
        "siteCode": "JHJR",
        "ldgrGrp": "L",
        "coaGrpNm": "Security Deposit - Others",
        "coaGrpCode": "CASDR0500017",
        "coaGrpId": 310,
        "opening": 8500,
        "prdDr": 0,
        "prdCr": 0,
        "closing": 8500
    },
    {
        "siteCode": "JHJR",
        "ldgrGrp": "L",
        "coaGrpNm": "Security Deposit - Others",
        "coaGrpCode": "CASDR0500021",
        "coaGrpId": 310,
        "opening": 44000,
        "prdDr": 0,
        "prdCr": 0,
        "closing": 44000
    }
]
```

i am expecting o/p in variable b .Below is the  Expected output

```
[
  310    
]
```

I have getting 310 times null value in array and lenght 310 as displayed below

[image]

```
[
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
   // 310 times 
]
```

Below expression i have used

```
 var b = Array(...new Set(ldgrwisesum.map((x) => x.coaGrpId)));
```

Kindly help me on this.

Comment: Do not post images that just waste the space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misrepresenting the contents of the array. It is not `[null, null, ...]`, it is `[ , , , , , ...]`, i.e. not containing any elements whatsoever (neither `null` nor `undefined`), just 310 "empty slots". It is an array with length 310 and no elements, i.e. a [sparse array](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/javascript-the-definitive/9781449393854/ch07s03.html). And that is because you called `Array(310)` which means "create a sparse array with length 310". Note that if you had two different numbers in your set, it would have done what you wanted, because `Array(1, 2)` means "create array `[1, 2]`" - only with a single numerical argument it's different.

This is exactly why the [`Array` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Array) is not recommended anymore - because this often-unexpected difference in behavior would often lead to bugs. Instead, you can use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) or the spread syntax directly:

```js
const b = Array.from(new Set(ldgrwisesum.map(x => x.coaGrpId)))
// --- OR ---
const b = [...new Set(ldgrwisesum.map(x => x.coaGrpId))]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the way you creating array from set may be wrong.

Try to use [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) method

```
Array.from(new Set(ldgrwisesum.map(x => x.coaGrpId)));
```

Answer (score 0):

`Array()` literally nobody uses. Use instead just brackets `[]`

Try:

```js
let data = [
    {
        "siteCode": "ANKL",
        "ldgrGrp": "L",
        "coaGrpNm": "Security Deposit - Others",
        "coaGrpCode": "CASDR0500044",
        "coaGrpId": 310,
        "opening": 10000,
        "prdDr": 0,
        "prdCr": 0,
        "closing": 10000
    },
    {
        "siteCode": "AYDH",
        "ldgrGrp": "L",
        "coaGrpNm": "Security Deposit - Others",
        "coaGrpCode": "CASDR0500003",
        "coaGrpId": 310,
        "opening": 5000,
        "prdDr": 0,
        "prdCr": 0,
        "closing": 5000
    },
    {
        "siteCode": "BIAL",
        "ldgrGrp": "L",
        "coaGrpNm": "Security Deposit - Others",
        "coaGrpCode": "CASDR0500010",
        "coaGrpId": 310,
        "opening": 41400,
        "prdDr": 0,
        "prdCr": 0,
        "closing": 41400
    },
    {
        "siteCode": "BLSH",
        "ldgrGrp": "L",
        "coaGrpNm": "Security Deposit - Others",
        "coaGrpCode": "CASDR0500013",
        "coaGrpId": 310,
        "opening": 5000,
        "prdDr": 0,
        "prdCr": 0,
        "closing": 5000
    },
    {
        "siteCode": "BLSH",
        "ldgrGrp": "L",
        "coaGrpNm": "Security Deposit - Others",
        "coaGrpCode": "CASDR0500016",
        "coaGrpId": 310,
        "opening": 1178176,
        "prdDr": 0,
        "prdCr": 0,
        "closing": 1178176
    },
    {
        "siteCode": "BLSH",
        "ldgrGrp": "L",
        "coaGrpNm": "Security Deposit - Others",
        "coaGrpCode": "CASDR0500028",
        "coaGrpId": 310,
        "opening": -294710,
        "prdDr": 0,
        "prdCr": 0,
        "closing": -294710
    },
    {
        "siteCode": "CKBL",
        "ldgrGrp": "L",
        "coaGrpNm": "Security Deposit - Others",
        "coaGrpCode": "CASDR0500026",
        "coaGrpId": 310,
        "opening": 3890,
        "prdDr": 0,
        "prdCr": 0,
        "closing": 3890
    },
    {
        "siteCode": "CPLN",
        "ldgrGrp": "L",
        "coaGrpNm": "Security Deposit - Others",
        "coaGrpCode": "CASDR0500027",
        "coaGrpId": 310,
        "opening": 139371,
        "prdDr": 0,
        "prdCr": 0,
        "closing": 139371
    },
    {
        "siteCode": "DMR5",
        "ldgrGrp": "L",
        "coaGrpNm": "Security Deposit - Others",
        "coaGrpCode": "CASDR0500018",
        "coaGrpId": 310,
        "opening": 37200,
        "prdDr": 0,
        "prdCr": 0,
        "closing": 37200
    },
    {
        "siteCode": "DMR7",
        "ldgrGrp": "L",
        "coaGrpNm": "Security Deposit - Others",
        "coaGrpCode": "CASDR0500039",
        "coaGrpId": 310,
        "opening": 57000,
        "prdDr": 0,
        "prdCr": 0,
        "closing": 57000
    },
    {
        "siteCode": "JHJR",
        "ldgrGrp": "L",
        "coaGrpNm": "Security Deposit - Others",
        "coaGrpCode": "CASDR0500017",
        "coaGrpId": 310,
        "opening": 8500,
        "prdDr": 0,
        "prdCr": 0,
        "closing": 8500
    },
    {
        "siteCode": "JHJR",
        "ldgrGrp": "L",
        "coaGrpNm": "Security Deposit - Others",
        "coaGrpCode": "CASDR0500021",
        "coaGrpId": 310,
        "opening": 44000,
        "prdDr": 0,
        "prdCr": 0,
        "closing": 44000
    }
]

let result = [...new Set(data.map(d => d.coaGrpId))]

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this `[...new Set()]` just like `Array.from(new Set())`

```
const getProperData = [...new Set(data.map(e => e.coaGrpId))]
```